# IE Back Button reloads Facebook Page App instead of going back to fan page

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-9, facebook-page

when I go to a facebook fan tab, and use IE, and click back, it doesn't do anything because static.ak.facebook.com/platform always gets in the way. The back button works great for all other browsers. There apparently is a proxy page that does a redirect back to the fan tab. There was facebook question about two years ago on the same question, but apparently no one has solve it yet.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/488616664498524/?browse=search_5005f9633ba073b61930185

I noticed that a some fan tabs have the same problem, where you have to click back 15 to 20 times to actually go back to the fan page, while others only take 2 backs. I was wondering if anyone knows a solution to this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I figured it out..

No matter what there will have to be at least 2 backs, but the Page Tab URL can't just be

example.com/stuff/

It has to be

example.com/stuff/index.php or index.html etc.

Or you can do example.com/stuff but you won't be able to get the signed request.